# cmake aruco with predefined dicts for java

Tags: java, opencv, aruco

I generated the opencv v4.7.0 using

- `cmake`
- `opencv sources`
- `opencv-contrib`

The jar and the referenced library are usable within the ide. This includes also the aruco module from opencv-contrib. Nevertheless the predefined dictionaries of aruco are missing.

Did I miss a point during cmake?

Comment: It seems that the aruco predefined dictionaries are no longer present from version `opencv_contrib` `v4.7.0`; I decided to go with the prior version.

Comment: please file an issue about this. someone has been changing many things in the aruco module with... "less than desirable" care for keeping it working.